# Isn't there a page where I can see all my inbox items?

Tags: support, global-inbox

Isn't there a page where I can see all my inbox items? I don't  like and I don't want just the upper dynamic inbox item, on the menu, that has a limited width (much smaller than what I would like) and also a limited height. Both things are very annoying to use. So I imagine that a page like an old email inbox has been for decades, and still is very useful without any changes. I want to see my inbox here with the same idea: just a simple page with message and even some preview or resume of their contents, in a long list (or divided with a reasonable number of messages per page, numbered pages), and such page using most of the window width it gets.

Answer (score 4):

There's some for sure. The network wide inbox is located at https://stackexchange.com/users/6321188/balaco?tab=inbox. The link to it also can be found when you scroll the inbox in the top bar to the bottom.

> [image]

The per-site one is at `{site}/users/current?tab=responses`, i.e. for this site it's [there](/users/current?tab=responses).

Comment: How about the [api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox)? Or  [/inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox) api call, or [/notifications ](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/notifications)?

Comment: @Michael Wait, this doesn't appear to be necessary to use api there. (though I guess that's for the irony I didn't mention all the variants, right? :D)

Comment: Just a "this is a way that *might* work if you want to go that route. Quick rest call with an auth token and you've got it all.

Comment: Having to scroll to be able to see the way we want (so we don't want to look all of them) is simply too sillly! Practically a stupid way of hiding thing with a fake but apparently "modern" interface... I will put that url in a favorite...

Comment: Imagine this with emails: 'you can see all the 5284 emails you have, but before you do it you must scroll the page down with your mouse (keyboard is not allowed, so don't think about the "End" key!!)  to see the link to you "detailed inbox" page'. SillynessOverflow, that is...

Comment: And there is a silly catch, of course. The I will have to make one separate favorite for each URL StOv, StEx, ....

Comment: This only gets worse the more I think about it...